# How to filter the objects of an array with another array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have one NSMutableArray with 100 objects. This is original array.

I have another array that contains 20 objects which are also in the original array.

I want to display the original array in the view controller minus the objects in the other array.

How can I remove the existing objects from original array?

we can add objects to an array with

```
[filteredListCount addObjectsFromArray: currencyArray];
```

Is there a similar method or idea to filter the original array with the second array?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[originalArray removeObjectsInArray:existedObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

[filteredListCount removeObjectsInArray: currencyArray]

Comment: kubi answered first. so his answer is correct. my browser didnt show new answer while i was writing my own answer..